# VirtualHost causes a redirect loop

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have made a VirtualHosts for my subdomain but it keeps making a redirect loop.

For example: I enter beta.domain.com and it redirects to beta.domain.com/index.php/index.php/index.php/...
And gives me the Server has a redirect loop error message.

config:

```
<VirtualHost IP>
ServerName www.beta.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/beta/
</VirtualHost>
```

Can somebody help? Much appropriated thanks :)

Comment: That isn't a problem in the configuration info you posted above; it's a problem with a `RewriteRule` directive somewhere. Please post the rest of the config file and any `.htaccess` file(s) you are using.

Comment: @EdCottrell I don't have a .htaccess

Comment: Okay, that's why I said "any." You do need to post the rest of the config file, however. What you have posted can't possibly be causing the error.

Comment: @EdCottrell That's all the config file for that domain

Comment: Either there are more config files, or your PHP file is causing a redirect. Either way, what you have posted above isn't enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualHost allone will never do a redirect, look at some .htaccess rewrite on your DocumentRoot
if you are in trouble to find the .htaccess file disable it .htaccess by adding this to your VirtualHost config

> ```
>  <Directory /path/to_documentroot>
>  AllowOverride None
>  </Directory>
> ```

sorry the poor english